# Retrieving lost SIM PIN and PUK

Tags: applications, sim-card

If the SIM and PUK are stored on the SIM card, then why can't an Android application read this information and display it to the user?

Comment: For the same reason it doesn't display passwords?

Comment: Well, are passwords used to unlock the phone also stored on the SIM card? I'm not sure. In any case, if the phone is rooted, I can't see why all this information couldn't be accessed.

Comment: I can. It might be encrypted or hashed. Just take a look at system passwords on Linux: `/etc/passwd` doesn't have them anymore, and `/etc/shadow` just stores hashes – so not even root can read them. That's how security is supposed to work: root might be able to change a password, but should not be able to read (compromise without the user's knowledge).

Comment: A PUK, being 8-digit long, could be stored as a hash, but a rainbow-table attack could recover the original PUK if some timing mechanism to introduce a delay is not built into the SIM. And as far as the PIN goes, I doubt it would make sense to hash such a short number consisting of only 4 digits. Besides, I've not seen any programs on the google play store which can crack the PIN and PUK, or even read the corresponding hashes on the SIM if they existed. So, why don't these programs exist, if these options are possible, or, why aren't they possible? Thanks.